# Animated transformation from square to right trapezoid filled with gradient

Tags: css, transform, css-animations

I need to get an animation from square to right trapezoid filled with gradient. Here is what I've done: http://jsfiddle.net/7Aav7/.

```
#box {
    border-bottom: 100px solid transparent;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 50px;
    background-origin: border-box;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue, yellow);
    border-right: 0px solid white;
    -webkit-animation: rightTrapezoid 2s infinite alternate;
}
@-webkit-keyframes rightTrapezoid {
    to {
        border-right-width: 50px;
    }
}
```

But at this case my right border is white - and I need it to be transparent (not to be tied with body color). Is there any way to achieve this? Is that possible with css transforms? Thank you everyone for help.

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as you need the borders to get the trapezoid to be with the correct background. At the same time you don't want the right border to have that same background.

Comment: and with css transforms?

Comment: What about using a canvas and draw the shape yourself, or using raphael.js if you need to support older browsers?

Comment: but you know that CSS has it's limits?

Comment: so its impossible with css transforms? I also thought about perspective and to hide left part http://jsfiddle.net/HJPfG/9/ but its kinda tricky..

Comment: I will not say that it is not possible, but in the moment I have no idea in my mind for a trick or hack that brings you even near to the state you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, using a wrapper div.

The (boring) html:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="inner">
</div>
</div>
```

in the inner div, standard stuff. Only note the negative left

```
#inner {
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    left: -50px;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(blue, yellow);
    -webkit-animation: rightTrapezoid 2s infinite alternate;
}
```

and the animation, just using skew

```
@-webkit-keyframes rightTrapezoid {
    to {
        -webkit-transform: skew(30deg,0deg); 
    }
}
```

This generates animation on both sides of the div. To hide the left side movement, I use the container div, with overflow hidden (using the negative left of the inner div)

```
#container {
    left: 55px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

[here is the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Se9VK/)